# Add .gitignore to committed files

Tags: git, magento, svn

I am using git mistakenly i have not ignored the jpeg files in the gitignore.

I my repo increasing day by day because of the images.

```
git rm --cached blog/wp-content/upload/*
```

after running this command i am getting following error

```
fatal: pathspec 'blog/wp-content/upload/' did not match any files
```

Please let me know how to un-track these files.

Also i need to untrack magento files which i have committed to repo

Comment: Well, you're using the right Git command to untrack files... but are you running it at the right place Is there really a subdirectory called `blog/wp-content/upload/` in the directory where you are running that command?

Comment: @Manoj Just in case, would using sungle or double quotes be useful? `git rm --cached 'blog/wp-content/upload/*'`  or `git rm --cached "blog/wp-content/upload/*"` (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/12066184/6309)