# How can I add some specific files in a directory in git?

Tags: node.js, git

```
./main
  ../firstDirectory 
    ../file_A.js
    ../file_B.js
    ../file_C.js
    ../file_D.js
    ../file_E.js
```

I'm trying to create a script that only adds the changes for specific files in some directory, such as `file_A`, `file_C` and `file_E`

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
  add: "git add <path pattern>"
}
```

I have tried something like `git add ./main/firstDirectory/*.js`, but that will add all files. Is there any path pattern that I can specify so `git add` can know to only add the changes for specific files ?

Update:
Although this works:

`git add main/firstDirectory/file_A.js main/firstDirectory/file_C.js main/firstDirectory/file_E.js`

I'm looking for a dynamic solution(pattern), so I won't have to update the script if consider adding more files in future.

I have tried a lot, and couldn't to come up with an answer. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `git add main/firstDirectory/file_A.js main/firstDirectory/file_C.js main/firstDirectory/file_E.js`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That works, but I'm looking for something more dynamic, so I won't have to keep updating the script

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git -C ./main/firstDirectory add '*.js'
```

Since the `-C` option does a cd into the right folder, `*.js` without quotes should work too.

See "[“git add” using wildcard is not functioning as I hoped - must I cd into specific directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066228/6309)".

That will add all the files only if they have changed.

But if you want to keep the other files *untracked* (meaning never add them in the first place), then you can whitelist the files you want to monitor:

Write in a .gitignore in that folder:

```
*
!file_A
!file_C
!file_D
!file_E
```

That way, even if the other files change, they won't be added by a `*.js`.

Make sure those files are not tracked:

```
cd main/firstDirectory
git rm --cached -- *.js
```

Comment: I think this will still add all files(file_A, file_B, file_C, file_D, file_E). However, I want to add only file_A, file_C and file_E.

Comment: I put them in a .gitignore file but I keep getting this error:
`The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:`

Comment: Make sure those files were not tracked before

Comment: It seems like the command is not running correctly. It keeps throwing errors. That's how I have it

`
"scripts": {
  add: "git -C ./main/firstDirectory add *.js"
}
`

Comment: For checking if a file ignored, git check-ignorr -v -- afile

Comment: Yes, it seems like they were tracked it before. How can I make them untracked ?

Comment: Go in the folder and do git rm --cached -- *.js

Comment: They are not tracked; however, I still keep getting this error:
`The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:`

Thanks a lot for being really patience with me

Comment: The  check-ignore command I mentioned before will help you determine which rule is involved